# Projective modules restricted to smooth curves

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

I want to prove a coherent sheaf $M$ on $X$ is locally free if and only if this is true for $M|_{X'}$ ,
for all smooth curves $X'$ mapping to $X$. I think the only if direction is obvious. For the if direction, a coherent module is flat if and only if it is projective, for Dedekind domains if and only if torsion free as well. So I am thinking of using Tor$_1$. There is [local criterion for flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_criterion_for_flatness), but I am not sure if this will help.

This is used at the beginning of the proof of Proposition 5.13 of [Gaitsgory's lecture notes](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/267y/catO.pdf).

Comment: Am I doing something incorrect here? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384569/projective-modules-restricted-to-smooth-curves) on MO. This is a community-wiki recording of the accepted answer there by user [abx](https://mathoverflow.net/users/40297/abx) so that this question can also be marked as answered.

> Assume that $X$ is integral and smooth (as in Gaitsgory's notes). For any two points $x,y$ in $X$, there is a smooth connected curve $C$ passing through $x$ and $y$. Since $M_{|C}$ is locally free, this implies $\dim M_x/\mathfrak{m}_xM_x=\dim M_y/\mathfrak{m}_yM_y$, where  $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$. But this implies that $M$ is locally free.

Answer (score 1):

In Borel's book "Algebraic D-modules" the following result is proved:

**Propositon VI.1.7** Let $X$ be a regular scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. If $M$ is a $D_X$-module that is coherent as $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then $M$ is locally free.

It seems you do not need the connection to be flat for the result to hold.
It also seems to hold over any field $k$ of characteristic zero.